# is there any other option like local storage but easy to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i'am beginner and lately i have been studying local storage but i found it a little hard to understand.So is there any easy alternative to local storage that does a similar work to store data.

Comment: `localStorage` is **easy to use**

Comment: Can't really get an more trivial than a key-value store .. [there are even of MDN examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Since you're unlikely to find anyone here that agrees with you that localStorage is hard to understand, you should probably change your question to explain what you don't understand about it, because it really is not hard at all.  In fact, it's one of the easier ways to store stuff.

Comment: According to above users, localStorage is the most simple way to store data in javascript. In other languages, store data is even harder.

Comment: Can you explain Why it is hard? We can give you solutions.

Comment: Try `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it does not seem to most people that it is hard to store data in LocalStorage, I guess I'll just explain how it works:

It's a simple key/value storage where both key and value are strings.  You create the key (any string you want to use to identify a particular data item) and then you associate a value with that key when you save the value.

Let's say you have a username in a variable called `username` that you want to remember in LocalStorage.  All you do is make up a key that you're going to store it under.  Lets use "userID" and then to store it, it takes a single line of code:

```
var username = "Bob";
localStorage.setItem("userID", username);   // saves "Bob" to the "userID" key
```

That's it.  The username is now stored in local storage.

Now, lets supposed in some other web page on your site, you want to read the username associated with this particular browser.

```
username = localStorage.getItem("userID");  // will get "Bob"
```

---

Keep in mind that localStorage is per domain and is stored locally in the browser so each domain has its own set of localStorage and one domain cannot read the store of another domain.  It is similar to cookies in that regard (except that cookies also have a path and an expiration that can be additional features).  localStorage values are not sent to the server like cookies are.  They are only kept local in the browser and are accessible via Javascript.

Comment: nice explaination

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a scenario New User Registration page.

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="a" />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="b" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="c" />
```

First **store** required data locally.

```
localStorage.UserName=document.getElementById(a);
```

Now **retrieve** the stored data

When user comes back to you can greet him with Welcome message

```
if(localStorage.UserName){alert("Welcome back "+localStorage.UserName)}
```

localStorage.UserName is equal to localStorage.setItem("UserName"," ")

To prevent javascript alert popup Welcome message each time user loads page, you can prevent this with the use of **sessionStorage**

sessionStorage usage is similar to localStorage **but the value in sessionStorage expires when user closes the browser or tab**

**Code with localStorage and sessionStorage**

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="a" />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="b" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="c" />
```

First **store** required data locally.

```
localStorage.UserName=document.getElementById(a);
```

Now **retrieve** the stored data

When user comes back to you can greet him with Welcome message. But prevent repetition with sessionStorage

```
if(!sessionStorage.ShowWelcomeMessage)
{
 if(localStorage.UserName){
  alert("Welcome back "+localStorage.UserName)
 }
sessionStorage.ShowWelcomeMessage="Done"
}
```